# Return results for Ubuntu Updates in a Variable

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04, apt

I am trying to get the result from /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check on a Ubuntu 16 Server into a Array to make a XML response for a monitoring tool, but somehow the value of this apt-check just refuses to get in my Variable. For **simplicity** sake, I have **omitted the XML creation** part.

```
#!/bin/bash
APTCHECK="/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check"
APTResult="$(${APTCHECK})"
echo "Result is $APTResult"
exit 0
```

if you now run this code with bash -x you will see that the result is returned to the Terminal, but not assigned to the Variable. If I substitute the "command" to something simple like "ls -lah" everything works fine.

I just don't know why this is not working ? Anybody ?

Comment: redirect stderr: `2>&1`

Comment: Your script does absolutely nothing useful, though. It's mostly harmless but loses the exit code. An absolute improvement would be to remove the [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) but then losing the real exit code will be the *only* effect.

Comment: Assigning to an array would look like `array=(command >&2)` but the order of the array won't be particularly predictable or useful, and then the syntax for retrieving the array will be a new complication.

Comment: bash -x ./APTCHECK.sh 2>&1 does not help :( 

For some reason the call to apt-check returns it's result to the screen and not into APTResult. ?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-check` prints to the stderr, so you need to capture that instead with `aptresult=$(/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check 2>&1)`.

The other option is with the `--human-readable` switch, which'll print to the stdout. The only problem then is that you have to parse the text output (unless the text output is what you actually want).

Comment: Is there a easy way to find out when a script sends it's output to stderr?